# super + left/right doesn't work in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome

I want to split my screen to view two applications at the same time using super + left/right but it only works for some default applications such as firefox, terminal, skype or settings. Other applications such as chromium, vscode, files aren't applicable. The combination is still available in keyboard setting, though

Comment: For which cases is it not working?

Comment: @vanadium I can split screen into two to use two terminals for example by pressing "super + left/right" but I cannot do it with vscode, chromium, or files

Comment: Please add this extra information to your question: use "edit".

Comment: Just saw a very similar question here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225245/i-want-to-split-my-ubuntu-display-screen-but-unable-to-do-it, but the user did not yet specify its version. I wonder if that could be a bug that crept in in your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

when I faced this problem, my nvidia-driver hasn't been installed yet and my resolution was 1024*768. After I install nvidia-driver properly and increase the resolution up to 1368*768, the problem solved