# How to split my Ubuntu display screen?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, google-chrome, skype

I really needed to split several applications while working on Ubuntu and I was tried with Super+ left/right shortcuts to operate it properly and it was worked on various applications like Skype, social media websites, downloading websites, my personal business website, and files manager.

But when I try to open other applications like Chrome and VS Code etc then the shortcut key code does not work in it.

Then I checked the various queries and suggestions tips available on the internet but still do not get the solution. Is there is any issues related to my computer system or application where it shows error while performing shortcut keys?

I always update my Ubuntu application and browser but still do not get success.

Comment: You haven't specified your OS/release details, where the default desktop can vary on release...

Comment: Very similar recent question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224893/super-left-right-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu-18-04?noredirect=1#comment2060480_1224893

Comment: Hi Henry. I have edited this question (currently in the review queue) and also one from you at Stack Overflow, to remove the links to a commercial website. In general we do not allow external links unless they are particularly relevant, and even then we tend to allow them only if the question is not dependent on them (since links change and break). Neither were relevant in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and solved it today. You can check it here.
[super + left/right doesn't work in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224893/super-left-right-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu-18-04/1225288#1225288)